# trimToSize() метод класса StringBuilder, для чего нужен?

Tags: java

```
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("polodik");
    stringBuilder.setLength(50);
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.capacity());
    stringBuilder.trimToSize();
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.capacity());
    System.out.println(stringBuilder);
```

результат в консоли:

```
50
50
polodik
```

про метод trimToSize()

> Attempts to reduce storage used for the character sequence.
>     If the buffer is larger than necessary to hold its current sequence of
>     characters, then it may be resized to become more space efficient.
>     Calling this method may, but is not required to, affect the value
>     returned by a subsequent call to the {@link #capacity()} method.

И так вопрос: Что делает и как правильно использовать метод trimToSize, чтобы увидеть хоть какое то влияние на результат в консоле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

метод `trimToSize()` класса StringBuilder и StringBuffer уменьшает размер символьного буфера до минимального допустимого значения

Правда у вас задан размер строки `setLength(50)`, по этому вы и не видите разницы

Вот так посмотрите:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("polodik");
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.capacity());
        stringBuilder.trimToSize();
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.capacity());
        stringBuilder.setLength(50);
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.capacity());
    }
```

Comment: хммм... получается базовый размер capacity == 16.  При добавлении "polodik" , capacity увеличивается размером +7 и  получается 23. Потом через trimToSize избавляется от пустых 16 как там его называть? ладно назовем - "пустых мест". Но вот остается пробел в понимании. А почему setLength мешает trimToSize сделать свою работу? (Да я недостаточно хорошо понимаю тонкости отличии setLength & capacity)

Comment: хотя также интересно, почему capacity не остается одним и тем же при добавлении "polodik", получается "polodik" не помещается в capacity а добавляется как новый кусок связанных символов?

Comment: По умолчанию в *stringBuilder* зарезервировано место для размещения 16 символов.
При выполнении `StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("polodik");` **вы передаете конструктору строку**, она копируется в объект **и дополнительно резервирует место еще на 16 символов**, вы можете задать целое значение `int` тем самым зададите размер буфера.

Comment: `capacity()` - выводит размер буфера, `length()` - длину объекта, `setLength` - устанавливает длину строки и заполняет нулевыми символами `\u0000`

Comment: Ок. Думаю достаточно. Спасибо за помощь.